# Unreasonably large negative number when using =NETWORKDAYS()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Hi there I am trying to use the `=NETWORKDAYS` formula in Excel to calculate the number of workdays passed between two dates minus public holidays on a separate sheet. When I enter the correct formula I get an unreasonably large negative number like -29221 workdays between 2017-04-28 to 2018-04-24. I've tried to change the NumberFormat of the cells, ignoring public holidays etc. but I still get these numbers. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(2018-4-24,D2,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!E44:E61)
```

Couldn't find anything on the internet that would solve this.

Comment: The Excel calendar starts on 1/1/1900.  `2018-4-24` in your formula is a sum which equals 1990 (2018 minus 4 minus 24).  Day number 1990 is 12th June 1905 (count of days after 01/01/1900) so it's calculating the difference between the date in cell `D2` and the 12th June 1905.  Either of the supplied answers should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2018-4-24` probably isn't being read as a date value, insert it into a cell and change to general to get it's "value" or use it in `Date()` like so:

`=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2018,4,24),D2,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!E44:E61)`

Answer (score 0):

Static date is being read as text. Enclose it in quotes or use date function. Consider these options:

`=NETWORKDAYS("2018-4-24",D2,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!E44:E61)`

OR

`=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2018,4,24),D2,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!E44:E61)`

If it still doesn't work, check the cells that you're referencing. Make sure you're referencing dates or its equivalent value and not some random numbers.

Hope this helps..